# Wordpress rss feed filtering by title

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, mailchimp, newsletter

Is it possible to filter a WP RSS feed by title?

I have a client who wants to filter the feed by url.

For example:
If he visits the [www.example.com/feed/?s=One post,Another post](http://www.example.com/feed/?s=One%20post,Another%20post) the url should give back items which titles contain the **One post** or **Another post** expressions.

Is it possible? Or is there an other way that he can filter the posts as he wants in his mailchimp camapign?